# Banach fixed point theorem and interesting integral of arctan!

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, banach-fixed-point

Let's consider the follwing ecuation:
$$x(t)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \arctan\left(\dfrac{x(s)}{2}+t\right) ds, $$where $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Using *Banach fixed point theorem* show that this ecuation has a solution $x(t)\in C[0;\frac{1}{2}]$. 
I understand the theorem cited above, but I am a bit stroke by the equation. I mean, the solution of it is a contiuous function, right? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$x(t)-y(t)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \bigg(\arctan\left(\dfrac{x(s)}{2}+t\right)-
\arctan\left(\dfrac{y(s)}{2}+t\right) \bigg)\,ds 
=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\int_{\frac{y(s)}{2}+t}^{\frac{x(s)}{2}+t}\frac{dw}{1+w^2}\right)\,ds,
$$
and hence
$$
\lvert x(t)-y(t)\rvert\le \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left|\frac{y(s)}{2}+t-\frac{y(s)}{2}-t\right|\,ds=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\lvert x(s)-y(s)\rvert\,ds
\le \frac{\pi}{4}\max_{s}\lvert x(s)-y(s)\rvert.
$$
Finally, $\frac{\pi}{4}<1
$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Theta :C\left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]\to C\left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right],$

$$\Theta (x)(t) =\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \arctan\left(\dfrac{x(s)}{2}+t\right) ds,$$ then we have $$||\Theta (x)-\Theta (y)||_{\infty} =\sup_{0\leq t\leq \frac{\pi}{2}} \left|\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\arctan\left(\dfrac{x(s)}{2}+t\right)-\arctan\left(\dfrac{y(s)}{2}+t\right)) ds\right|\leq \\\\\leq\sup_{0\leq t\leq\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{|x(s)-y(s)|}{2} ds\leq\frac{\pi}{4}||x-y||_{\infty}$$
thus $\Theta $ is contraction and by Banach Fixed Point Theorem $$\Theta (x) =x $$ for some $x\in C\left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right].$